# Exclude results in Mysql, NOT IN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help to write an SQL but i have no idea in this case how. 
Tried many different options but nonthing worked.

I have 2 tables in my mysql database

```
users (id, name, lastname)
blocked_users (id, user_id, blocked_id)

users table
id  name    lastname
1   nick    james
2   james   dean
3   mike    bendon

blocked_users table
id  user_id     blocked_id
1   2           1
2   2           3
```

Example:

What i would like to do is display all users in users table but exclude in this case
those which are blocked by user_id 2.

So if i'm example logged in as Mike Bendon (id 3 in users table) 
i should not be able to se james dean (id 2 in users table) because he has blocked me.

Comment: I would rename that column to `blocker_id`. The `user_id` is the blocked one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure of how to run that with php, but I think this SQL should do what you asked:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT user_id FROM blocked_users WHERE blocked_id = $logged_id);
```

Edit after comment:
Sorry, I misread the `id` column name. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   users 
WHERE  id NOT IN (
       SELECT user_id 
       FROM   blocked_users 
       WHERE  blocked_id=$current_user_id);
```

Comment: Same here im getting:  Uknown column user_id